# Numerical quantum state tomography simulator

Tags: simulation, state-tomography

On a classical computer, I want to simulate a learning-based quantum state tomography of a qubit. We can formulate it as finding a parametrized unitary evolution that takes the unknown pure state to a known state. We measure on the basis of the known state (see [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.06580)). If we get the known state we proceed, otherwise we change the parameter of the unitary evolution slightly, until we obtain a large number of projections to the known state successfully. There are a lot of simulators listed in quantiki website and also in some previous posts here. Does anyone know a simple simulator to do that?

Comment: By "choose measurement settings based on the outcomes of the previous measurements", are you talking about something akin to making a measurement on a qubit, then doing a controlled gate to a second qubit, then measuring the second qubit to get the result in the controlled gate's basis? If not, please give an explicit example.

Comment: @vtomole I edited the post for a better clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the best choice is clearly [qutip](http://qutip.org/), a quantum computing simulator based in Python. It's free, and it has good documentation.

Let us know if you have any other queries beyond asking which simulator could do the job best.